# iBeacon not tracking beacons in --release mode in android

Tags: android, ionic3, release, uuid, ibeacon

We are working with ionic3 and using [iBeacons library](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ibeacon/) for beacons scanning. It is working fine in --debug and --prod mode but not working in --release mode for Android. No proguard is used. Below is code snippet:

```
let beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion(
          'deskBeacon',
          'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
        );

        this.ibeacon.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion).then(
          result => {
            // console.log('startRangingBeaconsInRegion', JSON.stringify(result));
          },
          error => {
            console.log(
              'startRangingBeaconsInRegion error',
              JSON.stringify(error)
            );
          }
        );
```

As mentioned above, working fine for --debug and --prod but not for --release version in Android. iOS is working fine for all. Permissions are also added in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

What could be the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would try making a clean app from scratch that does nothing but detect beacons and see if you have the same problem in release mode